# Is there any way to Convert byte array to String in modelAttribute?

Tags: arrays, spring-boot, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I have a model class called "Post" which has an attribute "postContent" as a byteArray.

```
public class Post{
byte[] postContnet;

//getters
//setters
...
}
```

So, I am using spring boot and spring form tag for getting the user's input using modelAttribute. The reason I am using byte array is I am using Ckeditor to get the WYSIWYG content.

```
    <form:form ...... modelAttribute="post">
   ...
    <form:textarea path="postContect" id="editor1">
....
    </form:form>
```

While inserting the post to DB, I did not convert anything and it is inserted in MySQL DB where the postContent column is Blob type. However, when I am retrieving the content back for the edit purpose, I am getting byte array rather it should be a String. In a controller, I am getting and sending the data to JSP as below:

```
....
Post post = postService.findByPostId(postId);
        if (post != null) {
            mv.addObject("title", "Edit Post");
            mv.addObject("post", post);
 ...
```

So, when I use JSTL in JSP, it prints the postContect as an array. I could get many references where converting the String to byte array and wise versa but here since I am using spring form and modelAttribute I am not sure where should I edit. How could I get back String in between?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the answer and it works for me. I am adding the comment here because someone who has a similar issue will get an idea.

1. I created Spring converter for a string to byte array

   @Component
   public class StringBase64ToByteArray implements Converter {

   ```
   @Override
   public byte[] convert(String source) {
       byte[] byteSource = null;
       System.out.println("StringBase64ToByteArray is called");
       try {
           byteSource = Base64.getEncoder().encode(source.getBytes("UTF-8"));
       } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return byteSource;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Then I created another converter to byte array to string

   @Component
   public class ByteArrayToStringBase64 implements Converter{

   ```
   @Override
   public String convert(byte[] source) {
       byte[] decodedString = Base64.getDecoder().decode(source);
       return new String(decodedString);
   }
   ```

   }
3. I have registered both converters to spring boot configuration
   @Configuration
   public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

   ```
   @Override
   public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
       registry.addConverter(new StringBase64ToByteArray());
       registry.addConverter(new ByteArrayToStringBase64());
   }
   ```

   }